# KeyError: 'date' Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, datetime, keyerror

````
```if __name__ == "__main__":
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format
temp1 = pd.read_csv('_4streams_alabama.csv.gz')
temp1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp1['date'])
def vacimpval(x):
     for date in x['date'].unique():
          if date >= '2022-06-16':
               x['vac_count'] = x['vac_count'].interpolate()  
               x['vac_count'] = x['vac_count'].astype(int)
for location in temp1['location_name'].unique():
    s = temp1.apply(vacimpval)```
````

**In the code above, I am trying to use this function for all the location so that I can fill in the values using the interpolate method() but I don't know why I keep getting an key error**

Comment: Print `temp1.columns`

Comment: Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'date', 'location', 'location_name', 'cases', 'deaths',
       'hosps', 'vac_count'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here you can find [examples of using .apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Your function doesn't return anything... It's not causing your error, but after that your code probably won't work either

Comment: 2. If you want to compare dates, you can't just `'2022-06-16'`. You are comparing to a string. See [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html)

Comment: 3. Your MAIN misconseption lies in the fact that you think that when you are iterating like `for location in temp1['location_name'].unique():`, you are somehow changing your  `temp1`. That's not true: `temp1` stays the same. What you are changing is `location`

Comment: 4. When you deal with all the issues and want to make your code more efficient - use pandas methods, instead of looping over the unique elements and selecting them. See how to use [`groupby`](https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/)

Comment: By the way, the error message usually includes the line number on which the error occurred. It would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Source of the error:

Since there are only two places in your code where you access `'date'`,
and as you said, `temp1.columns` contains 'date', then the problem is in `x['date']`.

Comment: Can you suggests a possible solution to my code. I am basically trying to check if the date is latest as compared to 2022-06-16 and if it is then I am trying to interpolate the vac_count column to fill in the nan values

Comment: @ParthDevenGandhi, no, I can't, sorry. I can only suggest [Python Tutorial - `for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [Pandas Guide - Essential basic functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html). Also link in comments above - [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html), and examples of [`.apply`](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-how-to-use-the-apply-method-in-pandas/)